# Is there a way to call a modal with php in a search bar?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am Trying to call an action with php to link to another file with my search bar(so that when i click the search bar) results generate from another file or at least a modal pop up, I had a similar function occur to a previous button .

I've trying using GET and adding the url into the echo but.. no results.

Code i'm trying to get to work

```
 <div class="menuSearch">
   <form class="search-form">
       <input type="text" placeholder="Click here... ">
   </form>
 </div>
```

Code to my last button

```
      <div class="menutool">
        <a class="modal-link" data-modal-width="400" href= "<?php echo 
         $this->url('herd-info', array('action' => 'generate-menu')); >">
          <img id = "mag_glass" src="<?php echo $this 
            >basepath("/img/magnifying-glass-3-16.ico")?>">
        </a>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('your id or class').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('your_modal_id or class').modal('show');
})
```

After modal popup click on button that you apply and call a function that function will submit your form
Using

```
$(".search-form").submit();
```

Comment: Thanks mate tried this but still not getting the data from the action to appear, not sure why the magnifying glass icon worked but my search bar wont.

Comment: Can you show your code what you tried

Comment: $('.menuSearch').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.modal-link').modal('show');
})